# Query not executing when adding a parameter

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

I am using OleDB provider for Access database , developing in C# , VS2010

I have a **Products** table and **Suppliers** table

When I debug this code :

```
//open connection
con.Open();

//set command query for inserting a product
com2 = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Products (ProductName,Model,Provider,Manufacturer,ReleasedDate,Quantity,SupplierID) 
VALUES (@name,@model,@provider,@manf,@date,@quantity,@supp)", con);

/* ADDING PARAMETERS TO THE COMMMAND */
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", textBox2.Text);
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@provider", textBox4.Text);
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manf", textBox5.Text);
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text));
//  com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));

/* Getting the ID of the Supplier by his/her/it name and adding the value as a parameter */
com = new OleDbCommand("Select SupplierID from Suppliers WHERE SupplierName=@name",con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",comboBox1.SelectedValue);
int str = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supp", str);

//INSERT EXECUTION
com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Product Added To Stock");
con.Close();
```

The program runs fine and executes the Query , but when i **uncomment** the line

```
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
```

and Edit `com2` Query string to :

```
com2 = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Products (ProductName,Model,Provider,Manufacturer,ReleasedDate,Quantity,SupplierID,Price) 
            VALUES (@name,@model,@provider,@manf,@date,@quantity,@supp,@price)", con);
```

The program crashes at line  `com2.ExecuteNonQuery();` with this error:

```
You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Suppliers'.
```

**Notes:**

1. if you're wondering why I wanted to add Price, it's because I didn't
   add it from the first place
2. The Price column exists in the table `Products`
3. I deleted all the records in both tables
4. Price column type : Number - Long Integer
5. SupplierID is a primary key in Suppliers table
6. While debugging, `str` value was 4, which is the same value of one of the Suppliers

Comment: what is the column type?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Number - Long Integer

Comment: I susupect the SupplierID is wrong, row with that Id does not exists in Supplier Table

Comment: Yes. Make sure the `SupplierID` exists in the `Supplier` table, because it is a foreign key, it appears.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I debugged the program , and the `str` value is 4 , which is the ID of one of the Suppliers

Comment: Another way to debug is to copy your SQL statement into Access and replace your parameters with your values.

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: @ericpap what do you mean by transactions ?

Comment: Print out the value of str right after int str = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: @OlegGryb Read Notes (#6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving this Line:

```
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
```

After setting the @Supp parameter and see if the error persist

Comment: WOW ! didn't know Parameters addition order makes a difference

Comment: It seems like @S. Ahn was right. The order of the parameters does matters. Another posible solution is to move the block of code for getting supp before all the parameters addition.

Comment: The funny thing is that I was considering giving your answer, but I figured that having the OP change the query was easier than explaining where to move the code. Oh well, live and learn. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
com2 = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Products (ProductName,Model,Provider,Manufacturer,ReleasedDate,Quantity,SupplierID,Price) 
        VALUES (@name,@model,@provider,@manf,@date,@quantity,@supp,@price)", con);
```

to

```
com2 = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Products (ProductName,Model,Provider,Manufacturer,ReleasedDate,Quantity,Price,SupplierID) 
        VALUES (@name,@model,@provider,@manf,@date,@quantity,@price,@supp)", con);
```

You are sending the `price` as the `@supp` and the `supp` as the `@price`. Order matters. Other providers allow you the "bind by name," but not OleDb.

**UPDATE:** corrected query according to George T.

Comment: This would un-mismatch the columns. In the code, the @supp parameter is last.

Comment: Same error , (And what are you trying to do ?) your are changing paramaters indexes ! that's not right

Comment: You are putting Price in SupplerID and supp to Price

Comment: @GabourX, I added more information to my answer. The names of the parameters are almost irrelevant. You need to preserve the order when you added the to `Parameters`.

Comment: @user1914368, that link is for SqlClient. This is OleDb.

Comment: @S.Ahn but i always work with this format and it always work , but why in this case it doesn't?

Comment: @user1914368 That's interesting; I was looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user1914368 From your link: `The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters.`

Comment: @S.Ahn: You had the right idea but the query in your answer is wrong. You are correct that, with your change, the "supplier ID" value will be matched to "@supp". However, you only changed the order of "@supp" and "@price" and not the order of "SupplierID" and "Price" in the query. So SQL will match "@supp" to "Price".

Comment: @LarsTech,@S.Ahn, I removed my unhelpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is most likely due to the fact that the Supplier ID that you are providing as the value to your @sup parameter is not contained within the Suppliers table (foreign key constraint).  Is it possible that the data you are pushing in has changed between the running of your query string without the price parameter and the running of your query string with the price parameter?

*"You tried to perform an operation that would have violated referential integrity rules for related tables. For example, this error occurs if you try to change or insert a record in the "many" table in a one-to-many relationship, and that record does not have a related record in the table on the "one" side.
If you want to add or change the record, first add a record to the "one" table that contains the same value for the matching field."*  -- Microsoft Office Support

Comment: S. Ahn makes a good point, the issue is that you are passing the value of the price variable to the supplier ID field in your query, which is going to result in a foreign key constraint error.